# Problem in Bayesian Neural Networks PYMC3 code execution..error: ('Variable type field must be a TensorType.',)

Tags: python, neural-network, data-science, pymc3, bayesian-networks

I am trying to execute the following program and it is showing the following error:

```
('Variable type field must be a TensorType.', <Sparse[float64, csr]>, Sparse[float64, csr])
```

I don't know what is wrong with this line:

```py
acts_1= pm.math.sigmoid(pm.math.dot(ann_input, weights_in_1))
```

Can anyone help solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

#### Program:

```py
import theano.tensor as tt  
import pymc3 as pm

X = x_vector.astype(floatX)
Y = y.astype(floatX)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=.3)

ann_input = theano.shared(X_train.astype('float64'))
ann_output = theano.shared(Y_train.astype('float64'))


 # Initialize random weights between each layer
init_1 = np.random.randn(20, 6).astype(floatX)

with pm.Model() as nn_model:
    
    mu_a = pm.Normal('mu_a', mu=0., sigma=100)
    sigma_a = pm.HalfNormal('sigma_a', 100.)
   
    weights_in_1 = pm.Normal('w_1', mu=mu_a, sd=sigma_a,
                          shape=(20, 6), testval=init_1)
     
    acts_1= pm.math.sigmoid(pm.math.dot(ann_input, weights_in_1))

    
     # Define likelihood
    out = pm.Multinomial('likelihood', n=1, p=acts_1,
                         observed= ann_output)
    
    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(50000, step=step)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ('Variable type field must be a TensorType.', <Sparse[float64, csr]>, Sparse[float64, csr])

Answer (score 1):

I solved the above error by converting the sparse input matrix to dense input matrix
....Thanks for all sugeestions....